# I can't set the time when creating a 'modal box'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**About the project:**

- There's a table. In this table I have 3 columns called "name", "surname" and "more".
- Pressing 'More' will activate the 'modal box'.
- In the "Modal Box" box there is more information about the person.

**Problem**

- The 'Modal box' runs slowly when it is first started (500ms). That's not problem. But when pressed a second time, it does not open according to the time.( 0ms ). Why?

```js
let backWall = $("#backWall");
let modal = $("#modalBox");
$(".more").click(function(){
    backWall.show(0);
    modal.show(500);
  });
$(".close").click(function(){
  backWall.hide(0);
})
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById("backWall")) {
    backWall.hide(0);
  }
};
```

```css
#backWall {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }

#modalBox {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #262626;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 25px; }
  #modalBox .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: .25s; }
    #modalBox .close:hover, #modalBox .close:focus {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.5);
      color: red; }

#more {
  font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="backWall">
      <div id="modalBox">
          <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">First Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Furkan</td>
          <td>Gulsen</td>
          <td>
            <button id="more" class="btn btn-dark more">MORE</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Allen</td>
          <td>
            <button id="more" class="btn btn-dark more">MORE</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>Quenn</td>
          <td>
            <button id="more" class="btn btn-dark more">MORE</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

---

Comment: Works for me in Chome. Could you describe what problem you see and what browser you use?

Comment: 'Modal Box' works. That's not problem. But when we press the key twice, it doesn't work at 500ms (this problem). It works immediately. (Browser: Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal pops up directly, because you don't use the proper `hide` function on the modal. Here's the fixed code:

```js
let backWall = $("#backWall");
let modal = $("#modalBox");
$(".more").click(function(){
    backWall.show(0);
    modal.show(500);
  });
$(".close").click(function(){
  backWall.hide(0);
  modal.hide(0);
})
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById("backWall")) {
    backWall.hide(0);
    modal.hide(0);
  }
};
```

```css
#backWall {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }

#modalBox {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #262626;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 25px; }
  #modalBox .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: .25s; }
    #modalBox .close:hover, #modalBox .close:focus {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.5);
      color: red; }

#more {
  font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="backWall">
      <div id="modalBox">
          <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">First Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Furkan</td>
          <td>Gulsen</td>
          <td>
            <button id="more" class="btn btn-dark more">MORE</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Allen</td>
          <td>
            <button id="more" class="btn btn-dark more">MORE</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>Quenn</td>
          <td>
            <button id="more" class="btn btn-dark more">MORE</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you never hide the modal.
The modal is a child of the backwall. Once you display the modal the 1st time, it's now visible on the backwall. So toggling the backwall now dictates if the modal shows. 
To get the behaviour I think you are after, just hide the modal when you hide the backwall.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, `modalBox` is inside `backWall`.

- On the first click, you're displaying both of them.
- When you click on the close button or the backwall, you're setting `display:none` to the backwall (and, since your modal is inside, it is also hidden).
- Now, when you do a second click on 'More', this statement `backWall.show(0);`will display the backwall AND it's contents (including the modal).

A quick solution is to hide both of them:

```
let backWall = $("#backWall");
let modal = $("#modalBox");

$(".more").click(function(){
    backWall.show(0);
    modal.show(500);
  });
$(".close").click(function(){
  backWall.hide(0);
  modal.hide(0);
})
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById("backWall")) {
    backWall.hide(0);
    modal.hide(0);
  }
};
```

https://jsbin.com/vubizelonu/edit?html,css,js,output